# With two res directories per build variant, Gradle stopped tracking changes in resource files

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I, quite innocently, switched to using [different app icons for each product flavour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460095/how-to-provide-different-launcher-icon-per-product-flavour) along these lines:

```
sourceSets.production {
    res.srcDirs = ['res', 'res-production']
}

sourceSets.beta {
    res.srcDirs = ['res', 'res-beta']
}

sourceSets.internal {
    res.srcDirs = ['res', 'res-internal']
}
```

Thing is, after that, **Gradle stopped noticing changes in any layout files**, such as `res/layout/activity_faq.xml`, and **requires a clean build each time**, if I want my XML changes to be included in the APK.

I first thought this was an Android Studio problem, but in fact I can reproduce it with pure Gradle, on the command line, simply looking at the files that appear under `build/res/all/internal/debug/layout`.

When I run `./gradlew assembleInternalDebug`, it outputs:

```
:compileInternalDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preInternalDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:prepareInternalDebugDependencies
:compileInternalDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileInternalDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateInternalDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:mergeInternalDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeInternalDebugResources
:processInternalDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processInternalDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateInternalDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileInternalDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:preDexInternalDebug UP-TO-DATE
:dexInternalDebug UP-TO-DATE
:processInternalDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:validateDebugSigning
:packageInternalDebug UP-TO-DATE
:assembleInternalDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Here, `processInternalDebugResources` is shown to be `UP-TO-DATE`, while I think it should **not** be, when there are changed resource files. Before the icon-per-flavour change, in  similar Gradle output, `processInternalDebugResources` was *not* shown up-to-date.

Question is, **any way to fix this, or did I stumble upon a bug in Android Gradle plugin?**

My `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-core:0.14.2'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.14.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.2.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    productFlavors {
        production {
            packageName "fi.company.app"
        }
        beta {
            packageName "fi.company.app.beta"
        }
        internal {
            packageName "fi.company.app.internal"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    // Custom res directories for different flavors; used for 
    // setting different app icon.

    sourceSets.production {
        res.srcDirs = ['res', 'res-production']
    }

    sourceSets.beta {
        res.srcDirs = ['res', 'res-beta']
    }

    sourceSets.internal {
        res.srcDirs = ['res', 'res-internal']
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            // ...
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle 1.9; Android Gradle plugin 0.7.3.

**Edit**: For other reasons, I switched from product flavours to [custom build types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21006552/56285) for my app icon customisation needs. This problem still remains, so at least this isn't product flavour specific.

Comment: If I comment out `sourceSets.internal` in the above config (and restore the app icon to its default place under `res`), Gradle starts noticing changes just fine again. So indeed the problem is related to the per-flavour resource dirs.

Comment: I haven't looked at it in detail, but it sounds like it's worth filing a bug.

Comment: @Scott: I looked around, and this looks like the same issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60154 I left a comment there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, got this fixed. It turned out to be a small problem in my `build.gradle`.

What helped me was trying to upgrade to Gradle plugin 0.9.0, after which I started getting errors like these:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyProject'.
> SourceSets 'debug' and 'main' use the same file/folder for 'res': /path/to/MyProject/res
```

Well, I simply tried **removing `res.srcDirs = ['res']` from main sourceSets**, and that was it.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        // res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
    // ...
}
```

I left the rest of the sourceSets definitions untouched (`res.srcDirs = ['res', 'res-beta']` for `sourceSets.beta` and so on).

Everything works again: the build type (or product flavour) specific custom icons are in use, and Gradle once again correctly notices changes to resource files (e.g. layouts) in incremental builds!

<sup>(I verified that the problem indeed was in my config by testing with Gradle plugin versions  0.8.1, 0.9.0 and 0.9.3 with my changed `build.gradle`. Indeed, changes in the plugin were not what fixed this, even if 0.9.0 was the version that started giving me the useful error message.)</sup>

Possibly the **root cause** here was using "old project structure" and `build.gradle` that was originally generated by Eclipse. In any case, studying source sets and project structure more carefully in the [User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) might have helped too.

Answer (score 0):

I have the several build flavors for the same app with some changes, icons & splash screens. Each flavor have its own res folder. When I build the apps, each apk sizes around 50 mb :(.

So I fixed the issue by updating the build.gradle file with the following

```
`    sourceSets {
        main {
//            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
//            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        prod {
            manifest.srcFile 'prod/AndroidManifest.xml'
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/prod/res']
        }
        dev {
            manifest.srcFile 'dev/AndroidManifest.xml'
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/dev/res']
        }

}`
```

In the above, I commented `resources.srcDirs = ['src']`
and added

```
           `prod {
                manifest.srcFile 'prod/AndroidManifest.xml'
                resources.srcDirs = ['src/prod/res']
            }
            dev {
                manifest.srcFile 'dev/AndroidManifest.xml'
                resources.srcDirs = ['src/dev/res']
            }`
```